# How to use Terraform dynamic block

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to create a `azure` app gateway using `terraform` and my code looks like below:

`main.tf`

```
# Create Application Gateway
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "app_gateway" {
  name                = var.name
  resource_group_name = var.appg_name
  location            = var.appg_location
  .
  .
  .

#   backend_address_pool {
#     name = var.backend_address_pool_name
#   }

  dynamic "backend_address_pool" {
    for_each = var.backend_pools
    content {
      name      = backend_pools.value["name"]
      fqdns     = backend_pools.value["fqdns"]
      ip_addresses = backend_pools.value["ip_addresses"]
    }
  }    

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = var.http_setting_name
    cookie_based_affinity = var.cookie_based_affinity
    path                  = var.backend_http_settings_path
    port                  = var.http_setting_port
    protocol              = var.http_setting_protocol
    request_timeout       = var.http_setting_request_time_out_value
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

And here's my `variables.tf` - only `backend_pools` is mentioned here of all the variables

```
variable "backend_pools" {
  type = list(map(string))
}
```

And this is my `terraform.tfvars`

```
backend_pools = [
 {
   name = "pool1"
   fqdns = "fqdns1"
   ip_addresses = "10.0.0.0"
 },
 {
   name = "pool2"
   fqdns = "fqdns2"
   ip_addresses = "10.0.0.0"
 },
 {
   name = "pool3"
   fqdns = "fqdns3"
   ip_addresses = "10.0.0.0"
 }, 
]
```

What I am worried about is, according to the terraform [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/application_gateway#ip_addresses) it is mentioned that the data types of both `fqdns` and `ip_addresses` are `list`, then how can I change my `variables.tf` and `terraform.tfvars` and also `main.tf` which contain the `dynamic` block accordingly.

What I want to do is, create multiple backend pools and pass the values using a variable file or is it possible to create a `json` file with multiple backend pool and pass it to the `backend_pools` parameter?

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Do you get an error if you try that? What happens if you wrap the `fqdns` and `ip_addresses` in your `terraform.tfvars` in square brackets like `fqdns = ["fqdns1"]`?

Comment: Is there an actual error when you try to provision? I think your original code actually looks okay. If you want to set a variable constraint you can try `list(map(object(name = string fqdns = list(string) ip_addresses = list(string))))`. You will need to set each object as a new line with a tab, can't really format it on the comment reply here.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a mistake in your Terraform code:

```
dynamic "backend_address_pool" {
    for_each = var.backend_pools
    content {
      name      = backend_pools.value["name"]
      fqdns     = backend_pools.value["fqdns"]
      ip_addresses = backend_pools.value["ip_addresses"]
    }
  }
```

When you use the for_each loop, it should be:

```
dynamic "backend_address_pool" {
    for_each = var.backend_pools
    content {
      name      = each.value["name"]
      fqdns     = each.value["fqdns"]
      ip_addresses = each.value["ip_addresses"]
    }
  }
```

When you use the list in the for_each loop, you can try to change the type like this:

```
for_each = toset(var.backend_pools)
```

But the better way is to use the map, so you can change your variables like this:

```
backend_pools = {
 pool1 = {
    fqdns = "fqdns1"
    ip_addresses = "10.0.0.0"
 },
 pool2 = {
    fqdns = "fqdns2"
    ip_addresses = "10.0.0.0"
 },
 pool3 = {
    fqdns = "fqdns3"
    ip_addresses = "10.0.0.0"
 }
}
```

Then your dynamic block will look like this:

```
dynamic "backend_address_pool" {
  for_each = var.backend_pools
  content {
    name      = each.key
    fqdns     = each.value["fqdns"]
    ip_addresses = each.value["ip_addresses"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, in the file you have defined the variables values, shouldn't the `fqdns` and `ip_addresses` should be like `fqdns = ["fqdns2"]` and `ip_addresses = ["10.0.0.0"]
` respectively? within a list/array? and also how the variable declaration should look like? it is like `variable "backend_pools" {
  type = map(object({
    name         = string
    fqdns        = list(string)
    ip_addresses = list(string)
  }))
}`

Comment: @JananathBanuka Read it carefully, it's the type `map(object(string))`. So the value like `fqdns = ["fqdns"]` is not right. And each object is just for one configuration. Just try it.

Comment: I don't understand, according to your example, what is it going to be then? is it `map(object(string))` or something else?

Comment: @CharlesXu Why do you say the map syntax is better versus `list(object(string))`?

Comment: @rk92 The map syntax is a more suitable type for the for_each loop. And you can get a special backend pool with the key name.

Comment: @JananathBanuka Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?